# When exception is thrown in Action Method it makes second call to the Action Method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, exception

I am passing ViewData into master view and they are used also in the child views (they are propagated from master view).
We have customized HandleErrorAttribute

```
public class HandleErrorAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.HandleErrorAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        base.OnException(context);

        var e = context.Exception;
        if (!context.ExceptionHandled   
            || RaiseErrorSignal(e)      
            || IsFiltered(context))     
            return;

        LogException(e);
    }
```

which sends to customer Error view also with the same master view. RaiseErrorSignal(e) sends error to Elmah.
When exception happens, the ViewData are not passed to master page, and it causes another exception. I fixed exception in master view, and I introduced exception to action method for testing purpose:

```
Logger.Debug("Introducing bug in HomeController - About....");
        Logger.DebugFormat("Request url: {0}, Request refferer: {1}", Request.Url, Request.UrlReferrer);
        int b = 0;
        int a = 1 / b;
```

Then I eventually realized that after the exception was thrown in the action, master page was rendered with null ViewData, and then the action method was called again! here is a log - I had to change url here to "url of request":

2014-05-15 14:04:43.087 [DEBUG] [21]: Introducing bug in HomeController - About....

2014-05-15 14:04:43.088 [DEBUG] [21]: Request url: "url of request", Request refferer: "url of request"

2014-05-15 14:04:43.453 [DEBUG] [21]: Rendering master page for url: "url of request"...

2014-05-15 14:04:43.454 [ERROR] [21]: Master page: ViewData are null...

2014-05-15 14:04:44.769 [DEBUG] [21]: Rendering master page finished....

2014-05-15 14:04:48.603 [DEBUG] [20]: Introducing bug in HomeController - About....

2014-05-15 14:04:48.603 [DEBUG] [20]: Request url: "url of request", Request refferer: (empty)

2014-05-15 14:04:48.804 [DEBUG] [20]: Rendering master page for url: "url of request"...

2014-05-15 14:04:48.804 [ERROR] [20]: Master page: ViewData are null...

2014-05-15 14:04:48.904 [DEBUG] [20]: Rendering master page finished....

Could anybody explain that? Why is action method hit two times when there is exception?

The client receives error view (just once) and in elmah we got two times DivideByZero exception...